# Invoking a Python Script automatically after WordPress Posts

Tags: php, python, wordpress

Is there a plugin where I can execute the Python code I have written, as soon as a WordPress post has been published?

It takes command line arguments as inputs (the post URL and the tags of the posts), and for now, it works manually, but I'm hoping to automate the process.

Comment: how you publish your wordpress posts?

Comment: @WalidSaad Using the WordPress Admin Panel, as usual. But I want a script to invoke right after I do so.